# How to Compare two rows in Sqlite3 table?

Tags: authentication, sqlite, ios7.1

Here i m trying to compare details of rows values in consisting table.here my table contents [here my table
][1]
and also here my code

```
`-

     (IBAction)LogIn:(id)sender {

        sqlite3 *dbConnection;
        const char *dbpath = [[sharedobj getSandboxPath] UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt    *statement;


        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &dbConnection) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM NEWVALUES";


            const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbConnection,
                                   query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                     NSString *emailId = [[NSString alloc]
                                initWithUTF8String:
                                (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];
                    NSString *password  = [[NSString alloc]
                                initWithUTF8String:(const char *)
                                sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

                    if ([emailId isEqualToString:self.userNameField.text] || [password isEqualToString:self.passwordField.text]) {
                        NSLog(@"Login Credentials Correct");
                        CHECKViewController *checkobj=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CHECK"];
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:checkobj animated:YES];

                    }
                    else{

                           UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                              message:@"Login Credentials are Incorrect"
                                              delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK ", nil];
                        [alert show];
                    }
                    }
                    NSLog(@"Login Details %@ %@",self.userNameField.text ,self.passwordField.text );
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);


            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"SQLITE NOT OK");
                NSLog(@"Error %s ", sqlite3_errmsg(dbConnection));
            }
            sqlite3_close(dbConnection);
       }
```

imgur.com/QW6KX.png

when  enter first row values it working but when i enter second row values it not comparing .what i m doing wrong here?
Please give suggestions to fix this issue.
thanks in advance.

Comment: How often does this code call `sqlite3_step()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare user login values with Sqlite3 Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636669/how-to-compare-user-login-values-with-sqlite3-database)